# Extended Survival Plot Lines in R

Tags: r

I've obtained a survival plot from the following code:

```
    s = Surv(outcome.[,1], outcome.[,2])
    survplot= (survfit(s ~ person.list[,1]))
    plot(survplot, mark.time = FALSE)
```

person.list is just a list of 15 people.

When I plot this, the lines on my plot all end at different time points.  Is there a way to extend all the lines to make them end at a certain time point? (i.e outcome.[,1] is a time to event variable and I would like the survival lines on the plot to extend out to say 5(years) )

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer of how to do what you ask, but rather an explanation of why you should not do what you ask.

The lines stop where the data stops. Beyond that time, you have no information in order to make an estimate of the survival (this is in a traditional Kaplan-Meier survival analysis, as you have set it up). Therefore, the Kaplan-Meier estimate is not well defined beyond that time, and so extending that curve does not have any particular meaning. While graphically you could just draw a horizontal line at the same level as the last survival value, this is not really meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

This is code I posted to a similar question on rhelp a while ago:
http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2010-September/253817.html

```
  ?survfit   # to get a working example since you did not provide one
  lsurv2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, aml, type='fleming')
  plot(lsurv2, lty=2:3, xmax=300)  # drats, no effect of xmax
  str(lsurv2)      # so see the structure of the survfit object
  lsurv2$time[21] <- 300         #add a time value
  lsurv2$n.censor[21] <- 1       # mark as censoring time
  lsurv2$strata[2] <- 11         # add to count of group 2

  plot(lsurv2, lty=2:3, xmax=300)  # horizontal line to 300 for group 2
```

And this was Therneau's later response (presumably better than mine): http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2010-September/253879.html

```
plot(surv, mark.time=F, fun='event', xlim=c(0, 54))
  for (i in 1:length(surv$strata)) { #number of curves
     temp <- surv[i]
     lines(c(max(temp$time), 54), 1- rep(min(temp$surv),2))
     }
```

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that in that case, 1) there was data out to 54 (weeks), so the curves are well defined and 2) it was a Cox proportional hazards model that was being plotted which also makes extending the lines reasonable. The code given works, and does what the questioner asked, but may not be meaningful for the Kaplan-Meier case.

Comment: Sorry. Don't agree. It doesn't really matter whether this is a Cox model or a KM estimate. The horizontal line should be extended to the time of the last observed censored survivor. It forms the last estimate for the cumulative survival proportion. If it makes you feel any better, my upvote was the first and so far only response to your answer. I thought it was good to suggest that the questioner think carefully about what the line represented. It's just that I think the data stops at the last censoring time rather than the last event.

Comment: Actually, I agree with you. Drawing the curve out to the last censoring time is appropriate. There is information, and the ability to make an estimate, out to that time. Drawing it beyond the last censored observation is what I have issue with (and in the Kaplan-Meier case, the last censored event is likely different in each group). In the example you linked to, 54 weeks was the last censored observation, so drawing the curves to that point is appropriate. My comment was about how it _was_ appropriate in the example you gave where it may not be appropriate in the general case.

Comment: Great. We agree entirely, then.